# Remove duplicate rows from a list based on selected columns?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of a class and there are two columns in this class. Now i want to remove the duplicate rows from that class using specific columns. Like remove duplicate from first column only ,remove from send column only or remove from both.So for this i am using following code. Is there any best way to do this process because in future i will have 20-25 columns in this class and at that time i have to add 20-25 if statements in this function?

```
public List<ContactTemp> RemoveDupliacacse(List<ContactTemp> ContactTempList, List<string> objcolumn)
{
    List<ContactTemp> ContactTempListRemobdup = new List<ContactTemp>();
    if (objcolumn.Contains("CITY"))
    {
        ContactTempListRemobdup = ContactTempList.GroupBy(s => s.City).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
    }
    if (objcolumn.Contains("STATE"))
    {
        ContactTempListRemobdup = ContactTempList.GroupBy(s => s.State).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
    }
    return ContactTempListRemobdup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
public static List<ContactTemp> RemoveDupliacacse(
    List<ContactTemp> ContactTempList, 
    IEnumerable<Func<ContactTemp, object>> columnSelectors)
{
    IEnumerable<ContactTemp> ContactTempListRemobdup = ContactTempList;

    foreach(var selector in columnSelectors)
    {
        ContactTempListRemobdup = ContactTempListRemobdup
            .GroupBy(s => selector(s))
            .Select(group => group.First());
    }

    return ContactTempListRemobdup.ToList();
}
```

You can use it like;

```
RemoveDupliacacse(list, new List<Func<ContactTemp, object>> {
   (ContactTemp contact) => contact.State, (ContactTemp contact) => contact.City })
```

---

As you may already know, when you select multiple columns, the method removes duplicates for each column. Please check the following examples:

```
        var list = new List<ContactTemp> {
            new ContactTemp { City = "1", State = "1" },
            new ContactTemp { City = "1", State = "2" },
            new ContactTemp { City = "2", State = "1" },
            new ContactTemp { City = "2", State = "2" }
        };

        foreach (var contact in RemoveDupliacacse(
            list, 
            new List<Func<ContactTemp, object>> {
                (ContactTemp contact) => contact.State,
                (ContactTemp contact) => contact.City }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"City:{contact.City}, State:{contact.State}");
        }
        // This will output:
        // City: 1, State: 1

        // If you want to check duplication of the combination of the selected columns, 
        // you can do it like this;
        foreach (var contact in RemoveDupliacacse(
            list, 
            new List<Func<ContactTemp, object>> { 
                (ContactTemp contact) => new { contact.State, contact.City } }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"City:{contact.City}, State:{contact.State}");
        }
        // This will output:
        // City: 1, State: 1
        // City: 1, State: 2
        // City: 2, State: 1
        // City: 2, State: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your class like

```
public class ContactTemp
{
  public string CITY{} 
  public int STATE{} 

}
```

This list "ContactTempList" will have duplicates. you want to find and remove items from this list where CITY and STATE are duplicates.

I meant that,This will return one item for each "type" (like a Distinct) (so if you have A, A, B, C it will return A, B, C)

```
List<ContactTemp> noDups = ContactTempList.GroupBy(d => new {d.CITY,d.STATE} )
                              .Select(d => d.First())
                              .ToList();
```

If you want only the elements that don't have a duplicate (so if you have A, A, B, C it will return B, C):

```
List<ContactTemp> noDups = ContactTempList.GroupBy(d => new {d.CITY,d.STATE} )
                              .Where(d => d.Count() == 1)
                              .Select(d => d.First())
                              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via reflection with same signature, i.e. arbitrary number of columns:

```
public List<ContactTemp> RemoveDupliacacse(List<ContactTemp> ContactTempList, 
     List<string> objcolumn)
{            
    var type = typeof(ContactTemp);
    foreach (var column in objcolumn)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(column);
        ContactTempList = ContactTempList.GroupBy(x => property.GetValue(x))
                                         .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
    }
    return ContactTempList;
}
```